# Pyinstaller include folder

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have the following directories and I would like them to be included in my .exe

```
ProjectFolder
|---Python
|   |---App.py
|   |---data
|       |---pic.png
|       |---batch
|           |---batchscript1.bat
|           |---batchscript2.bat
|---App.exe
|---App.spec
|---Pyinstaller.exe
```

and I used the following batch script

```
pyinstaller ^
       --clean ^
       --onefile --noconsole ^
       --add-data="%~d0%~p0Python\data;." ^
       --distpath ./ ^
       "%~d0%~p0Python\App.py"
```

But when I open my App.exe no pictures are show. I think they are missed in the exe.

I include the png like this `self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('data\pic.png') )`

How can I properly include the `data` folder in my exe?